# Angular Universal - Is there a hook to run the code on a browser DOM

Tags: angular, universal, prerender, angular-universal

Is there any existing hook (or in progress feature) to execute code after the browser DOM was created?

I've already saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978500/check-width-of-component-rendered-by-angular-universal). Which really can't be the way to go.

Comment: is this question specific to angular-universal or an Angular app running in a browser?

Comment: @Maximus it's specific to universal. I'm looking for a way to execute code after the browser DOM was created.

Comment: @Orlandster do you achieve?